# Cognizione di causa

Tags: word-meaning, single-words

Ho trovato le seguenti parole su internet.

> Questi 'dottori' non hanno generalmente la più pallida idea dell'inferno che può significare intraprendere questa strada senza cognizione di causa.

Non capisco coda significa "cognizione di causa".

Comment: Hai consultato un vocabolario della lingua italiana? (Hint: [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cognizione/), punto 4.a.) Non puoi continuare a fare domande su singole parole o coppie di parole: i vocabolari esistono apposta per rispondere a queste domande. Sarebbe come se venissi a chiedere qual è la capitale della Germania anziché cercarlo su un atlante o in rete.

Comment: In english it could be translated "without a clue"

Comment: Non proprio, @RiccardoDeContardi, a meno che tu non ti riferisca a “non hanno generalmente la più pallida idea”.

Comment: @DaG quello sarebbe "(to) have not the slightest idea"

Answer (score 4):

"Con cognizione di causa" significa con una profonda conoscenza di un argomento, quindi "senza cognizione di causa" vuol dire senza una approfondita conoscenza dei fatti (che in inglese could be translated as "without a clear knowledge of the matter" e non "without a clue" che è tutta un'altra cosa).

Vedi anche [qui](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/con-cognizione-di-causa).